# How to get all the documents after a specific document In mongoDB , here suppose the 3rd one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch all the documents after the 3rd document that is {"_id": "19/07/2020/4","itemName": "w"}.

{
"_id": "19/07/2020/1",
"itemName": "q"
}

{
"_id": "19/07/2020/3",
"itemName": "a"
}

{
"_id": "19/07/2020/4",
"itemName": "w"
}

{
"_id": "20/07/2020/3",
"itemName": "r"
}

{
"_id": "20/07/2020/7",
"itemName": "t"
}

{
"_id": "20/07/2020/8",
"itemName": "y"
}

Comment: what have you tried? add your tried query and references in your question.

Comment: You need to `created_date` in your schema, which is good practice and can collect data based on the order created

Comment: actually I got a solution.